# union all two table but diff number of column

Tags: mysql, sql

`select count(*) as total FROM ( SELECT * FROM database1.orders WHERE number LIKE "11111111111111111" UNION ALL SELECT * FROM database2.orders WHERE number LIKE "11111111111111111" ) AS b`

but i got error :

The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

because run `SELECT * FROM database2.orders WHERE number LIKE "11111111111111111"` give me a result is null.

How to merge it with a query because with a query to help me process the pagination

Thank for helps !

Comment: but how if i need select all column and there are so many column because i need count for pagination and show data too ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do the aggregation before the `union all`:

```
select sum(cnt) as total
FROM ((SELECT count(*) as cnt
       FROM database1.orders
       WHERE number LIKE '11111111111111111'
      )
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT count(*) as cnt
       FROM database2.orders
       WHERE number LIKE '11111111111111111'
      )
     ) t;
```

Note I changed the string delimiter to be a single quote rather than a double quote.  It is good practice to use single quotes for string and date constants (and nothing else).

By the way, you can also do this using a join:

```
select o1.cnt1, o2.cnt1, (o1.cnt1 + o2.cnt1) as total
FROM (SELECT count(*) as cnt1
      FROM database1.orders
      WHERE number LIKE '11111111111111111'
     ) o1 cross join
     (SELECT count(*) as cnt2
      FROM database2.orders
      WHERE number LIKE '11111111111111111'
     ) o2;
```

This makes it easier to get the individual counts for the two databases.

Comment: the result would be somewhere between 0 and 2, do you mean sum(cnt) at the outer level?

Comment: yeah . but how if i need select all column and there are so many column because i need count for pagination and show data too ?

Comment: The different parts in the union need to be union compatible, that is they have to have the same number of columns and the columns need to have the same type. You can make them union compatible by introducing "dummy" columns like: `select a, cast(null as int) as b, c from t1 union all select a, b, cast(null as char) as c from t2`

Comment: yes i know , same column and type, problem in here select from t2 but result is empty

Comment: @hvtruong . . . If you need a bunch of columns, then you should ask another question with sample data and desired results.  This question is pretty clearly about getting `count(*)`, and changing the question after it has been asked is impolite to anyone who has tried to answer it.

Comment: oh i really sorry guys about that. my bad english. and thank @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 2):

The `orders` table in `database1` probably has a different number of columns than the table by the same name in `database2`.

Instead of using `select *`, select the columns you're interested in, like `select userid, productid, deliveryaddress, ...`.  Make sure you specify the same columns in both parts of the `union`.

For a `count(*)`, you could choose no columns at all, and select the value 1 for each row, like:

```
select  count(*)
from    (
        select  1
        from    database1.orders
        where   number like '111'
        union all
        select  1
        from    database2.orders
        where   number like '111'
        ) as SubQueryAlias
```

Or you can add the result of two subqueries without a `union`:

```
select  (
        select  count(*)
        from    database1.orders
        where   number like '111'
        )
        +
        (
        select  count(*)
        from    database2.orders
        where   number like '111'
        )
```