# How to union all two table but diff number of column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * 
  FROM database1.orders 
 WHERE number LIKE "111" 
 UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
  FROM database2.orders 
 WHERE number LIKE "111"
```

But i got error :

> The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Because run `SELECT * FROM database2.orders WHERE number LIKE "111"` give me a result is null.

I need to select all columns and there are so many columns because I need count for pagination and show data too ?

How to merge it with a query because with a query to help me process the pagination

Thank for helps !

Comment: same this asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24843201/union-all-two-table-but-diff-number-of-column/24843257

Comment: Could you please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE database1.orders` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE database2.orders` and show us a result of every output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UNION` operations requires **the same number of columns** on the two unioned querys plus this columns **have to be of the same type**. The error you are getting is because your table order on those two different databases has different number of columns.

So to achieve what you want you have to specify all columns from the `order` table from the database1 make sure that the `order` table on the database2 will have the same columns.

There are cases like yours that these tables doesn't match so you have to "create" and dummy column for the to match. Like this:

Say your `database1.orders` as the columns A, B, C and the `database2.orders` has the columns D, E, F, G the query would have to be:

```
select A, B, C, NULL as anAlias 
  from database1.orders
 UNION ALL
select D, E, F, G
  from database2.orders
```

If your `database1.orders` has less columns then the `database2.orders` you do the other way around.

Please, understand that to do this operation the columns has to be the same types. So on my example A matches D, B matches E and so on. The NULL value will be the missing column that will match with G

**Edit**

If your two databases order tables has the very same columns on each then your problem is because the two tables have a different creation order of the fields, like `database1.orders` has `A, B, C, D` and on `database2.orders` you have `A, C, D, B` **that's why you should not use** `select *` with a union clause.

Comment: yes, same column and type , problem in here select from database2.orders but result is empty record

Comment: then your problem is because the two databases have a different creation order of the fields, like `database1.orders` has A, B, C, D and on `database2.orders` you have A, C, D, B that's why you should not use `select *` with a union clause.